# Unicode Json Encode issue in PHP

Tags: php, json

in my database, it has some unicode character and when I :

```
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$response[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

The result is

```
[{
    "id": "151",
    "titlenews": "iPad2 ? iPhone Mini ????????????? ???????????????? Samsung Galaxy Tab",
    "photo": "ipad_1294990020.jpg"
}, {
    "id": "153",
    "titlenews": "???????????????????????? iPhone 5 ??????????????????? Apple",
    "photo": "iphone-5_1294996201.jpg"
}, {
    "id": "154",
    "titlenews": "Android ??????????????????????????????????? ????????????????????????????????????????????????????? 2010",
    "photo": "android_1295234852.jpg"
}]
```

Why it has "?", it should encode to any special character represent the unicode.

Thank

Comment: Did you send the appropriate charset headers?

Comment: Passed through http://jsbeautifier.org/ to make it easier to read...

Comment: sorry i don't really know about charset headers, what is that ? do we need to add sth more? thx

Comment: @sayvortana: [`mysql_set_charset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php). Also: the mysql extension is deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in comments (by Savartona) :

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8", $con);
```

Comment: -1 because: a) He wants to output JSON, so obviously he cannot use a `<meta>` tag (an HTTP header might do the trick); b) There is absolutely no indication that the problem is at the client; c) Even if none of this were true, 8859-1 would not be the correct charset because `json_encode` returns UTF-8.

Comment: By add
    mysql_set_charset("utf8", $con)

now it works fine thank guys, a

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use

```
function myencode(&$item,$key)
{
    $item=utf8_encode($item);
}

function my_json_encode($arr)
{
    if(is_array($arr))
    {
        array_walk_recursive($arr,myencode);
        return json_encode($arr);
    }
    else
    {
        return json_encode(array());
    }
}
```

And then to decode

```
function my_json_decode($json)
{
    return json_decode(safeJSON_chars(stripslashes($json)),TRUE);
}
```

Comment: For my problem, as @jon commented I need to add  mysql_set_charset("utf8", $con) and now it works fine